# Model have weird squares when selected in object X-Ray Mode

Tags: modeling, animation, object-mode

When selecting the torso in object mode X-Ray. It shows these weird squares.

[image]

And then when I try to animate it. The thing just turns into bits.
[image]

Comment: Please share your file. It's difficult to see exactly what's going on just from images. https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow the instructions on that page.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=nLdo81XQ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/nLdo81XQ/)

File here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have over 3000 duplicate vertices on that mesh. With the torso selected, go into Edit mode and hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select All. Then hit <kbd>M</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>Merge by Distance</kbd>. You'll briefly see a message in the status bar saying how many vertices have been removed.
[image]

Incidentally the same applies to the head object. You'll then have to parent the armature to the model again and all should be well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Imma try it.




It worked! Thanks a lot once again :D